# How can i get/show the file size in real time programmatically during recording screen in android

Tags: android, screen-recording

My recording code is below.

```
List<String> videotrack = new LinkedList<String>();

while (videoRecordContinue) {

Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
path = "/myTest.mp4";

videotrack.add(path);

Process proc;

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord --size 720x1280 --bit-rate 2000000" 
       + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + videoPath);

proc.waitFor();

}
```

And how to check encoding size in real time?